# If $В$ is an arbitrary member of the inner product space, show that $L_b$ is unitarily equivalent to $R_{B^t}$.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products, spectral-theory

Let $V$ be the space of complex $n \times n$ matrices equipped with the inner product $<A,B> = tr (AB^*). $

If $В$ is an element of $V$, let $L_b, R_b$ denote the linear operators on $V$
defined by $(a)$ $L_B(A) = BA$. $(b) R_B(A) = AB$.

If $В$ is an arbitrary member of the inner product space, show that $L_B$ is unitarily equivalent to $R_{B^t}$.

To prove this we have to find a matrix $U$ such that $UL_BU^* =R_{B^t}$.

I am not getting any clue to this...please Help!

Comment: $U$ isn't really a matrix. It should be a linear map on $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$. Hint: $(BA^t)^t = AB^t$.

Comment: $UL_BU^*(A) = U(A)L_B(A)U^*(A) = U(A)BAU^*(A)$ then how to apply your hint. @user251257

Comment: nope. The multiplication between linear map is composition. That is: $UL_BU^*(A) =U(L_B(U^*(A)))$.